# Clase URI y URL java

Tags: java

quiero realizar un programa con Java, donde el usuario ingrese ciertos datos por ejemplo el teléfono; y por la página web (ya esta programada con JavaScript) donde ya esta todo cargado, es decir, ingreso el teléfono y me devuelve el nombre, DNI, dirección, etc. Pretendo que el usuario solo vea el nombre y los demás datos no.

En resumen, necesito un intercambio de información entre la página y el programa.
Tengo entendido que la clase Uri de java.net debería servirme pero no se implementarla, podrían darme algunos ejemplos y decirme si eso funcionaria, desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerte la tearea mas sencilla utiliza Spring Boot con Spring Web , con un tutorial puedes ver como hacer servicios web para consumo de interfaces graficas.

EDIT: la clase URI lo unico que hace es representar una referencia [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), lo que se me ocurre de primera instancia es, si quieres realizar una aplicacion desde 0 puedes guiarte de [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_glassfish4.html) para crear un servicio web. Reitero que una aproximacion mas sencilla de realizar es crear un [servicio web con Spring Boot](https://carloszr.com/construir-servicio-web-restful-spring-boot-ejemplo/)

Comment: @BetaM De acuerdo con la liga , especifica que proveer una alternativa es valido como buena respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentar lo que me indicaste, gracias!!